# Miniconda3: No packages found in current win-32 channels matching issue

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

I've been following a guide in how to install Miniconda3 and use that to install different packages as *NumPy* and *SciPy*.

However, after installing Miniconda3 and opened a new project in PyCharm, the guide tells me that I should write:

```
conda install numpy
```

...which returned:

```
Fetching package metadata: Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-32/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-32/
.Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
...
Error: No packages found in current win-32 channels matching: numpy

You can search for this package on Binstar with

binstar search -t conda numpy

You may need to install the Binstar command line client with

conda install binstar
```

Which opted me to try:

```
conda install binstar
```

...which gave me the same error (even including the last line opting me to try `conda install binstar`).

I also tried, as a reference, to use `conda update conda` which resulted in `Error: No packages found in current win-32 channels matching: conda`.

I've added Miniconda when installing into my PATH variables. Does anybody have any clue regarding this?

EDIT: I have 32 bit system, and I've installed the 32 bit version of Miniconda.

Comment: Did you install **Anaconda** or **Miniconda**? If you installed Anaconda, then you already have `numpy` and `scipy`.

Comment: @Holt Oh sorry I misread my terminal. It says "Miniconda3", I read "Anaconda3". So it's Miniconda. Will edit.

Comment: It looks like you have a connection issue, maybe your firewall or a proxy is blocking your connection. Is there any special reason why you installed Miniconda instead of Anaconda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `conda` is not able to reach the package repository, so you likely have connection issues (your firewall might be blocking `conda`, or maybe you are behind a proxy).

Here are 3 workaround (if you cannot fix your network problem):

#### 1. Install Anaconda instead of Miniconda

You could install **Anaconda** from [continuum](http://continuum.io/downloads) website. Unlike Miniconda, it comes with a lot of pre-installed packages such as `numpy` and `scipy`.

#### 2. Install `numpy` from a pre-built conda archive

You can manually download the archives package from the [conda repository](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/repo), and install them using:

```
conda install numpy.tar.bz2
```

You need to download the archive for your operating system. Depending on the package you chose, you may have issue with dependencies...

#### 3. Download pre-built wheel files

[This site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)<sup>1</sup> provides tons of pre-built package for Windows, which are relatively easy to install:

```
python -m pip install numpy.whl
```

You should use the `python` executable that comes with `conda` (should not be an issue if you do not have multiple `python` installations on your system).

<sub><sup>1</sup> I am not the author nor the maintainer of this site, I just find it very useful when you want to install python packages on Windows and cannot use `pip`/`conda`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've installed Anaconda as a workaround, and it seems to be working as intended, so thanks!