# How to install python 3.7 on miniconda

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, anaconda, python-3.7, miniconda

I'm trying to install python 3.7 env for miniconda on my raspberry pi 4 model B.

But when I'm doing `conda install python 3.7`

I get  `Error: No packages found in current Linux-armv7l channels matching: 3.7`.

how can I install python 3.7 in some way on that miniconda?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create new environment with this python version:

```
conda create -n your_env_name python=3.7
```

And then you need to activate it:

```
activate your_env_name
```

[Here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) you will find more about conda environments.

Comment: also that doesn't work.
```Fetching package metadata: ....
Error: No packages found in current linux-armv7l channels matching: python 3.7*```

Comment: Here you might find answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371772/how-to-install-anaconda-on-raspberry-pi-3-model-b/56852714#56852714 .

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try with this command : `conda install -c anaconda python=3.7`

Tell us if this works

Comment: Hey, 
I get ```Error: No packages found in current linux-armv7l channels matching: python 3.7*```
when I try that command.

Comment: Does it say `Could not connect` ? If so, you might have connection issues (firewall or proxy blocking the access). You could try to look at this answer: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876038/miniconda3-no-packages-found-in-current-win-32-channels-matching-issue). You could for example try to install Anaconda instead of Miniconda if you have enough space on your pi

Comment: no, it does not say ```could not connect```.

Answer (score 0):

miniconda only have under python3.4 for armv7l
so you need to use python3.7 for armv7l(no anaconda or miniconda just python)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).